# Thumbnails dropping down instead if staying inline, css

Tags: css, ipb

I have a group of 4 randomly generated thumbnails created by a garage system on my website:

http://www.r32oc.com

You can see just under the main header area where they load.

They load up initially in the right order, and lined up nicely however when the page is finished loading they finish up on top of each other.

I have looked through the CSS and templates but think I am missing something obvious as to what is causing this. I have tried adding floats however they affect other elements on the page despite adding clearing divs.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be there is a problem in your external styesheet because at first ipb_gargae.css in load & after loading complete then your index CSS come .

Comment: Yes, adding it to the main ipb_styles.css seems to work.thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could add this css:

```
.main_thumb_block { float: left; }
```

Comment: hmm, strange. I have added the above to the css file, yet it is still dropping down for me. I will check for other instances.

Answer (score 1):

Add width to your class `class="ipsBox_container"`

```
.ipsBox_container
{
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

?